# Asymptotic notation meaning in transitive relation

Tags: analysis, notation, asymptotics

I'm attempting to prove the transitive relation on $\theta$ and I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of one of the symbols used. Here is the transitive relation:

$f(n) = \theta(g(n)) \bigwedge g(n) = \theta(h(n)) \longrightarrow f(n) = \theta(h(n))$

What does the "and" means with respect to $\theta(g(n)) \bigwedge g(n)$?

Comment: The "and" connects the two equations. $[f(n)=\theta(g(n))]\land[g(n)=\theta(h(n))]$.

Comment: Ohhhhh like a compound statement of sorts. Thanks!

Comment: One reason to write mathematical text in words not symbols... If $f(n) = \theta(g(n))$ and $ g(n) = \theta(h(n))$, then $f(n) = \theta(h(n))$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct interpretation is:

$f(n) = \Theta(g(n)) \quad \land \quad \left(g(n) = \Theta(h(n))\right) \quad \implies \quad f(n) = \Theta(h(n))$

It means that $f(n)$ is roughly a multiple of $h(n)$.

see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to understand the Theta function ($\Theta$).